# What's wrong with this network setup, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: networking, routing

I have the following network setup:

[image]

I have shown this setup to a colleague who is an experienced network engineer and he said my current setup isn't optimal.

After some back-and-forth we got to the bottom (I think) of the issue:

When a client from the home-network makes a request to the "server"-network the response is not coming from the original router (ASUS) but from the TP-Link Gateway router.

He said this is because of the metrics of the routing path (i.e. that the ASUS Router is skipped).

Now I can understand that this obviously creates some issues and I do have things that **do not** work like I cannot do a traceroute from the "home"-network with an IP that is from the server-network (e.g. `traceroute 10.0.0.100` "hangs" after 2 hops).

Also, pings from the home-network to the server-network are constantly showing "redirect host (new addr: *something*)".

**HOWEVER** I can visit (without a problem) an exposed web server from the home-network (i.e. visiting `10.0.0.100:9090` in a browser on the home-network WORKS)

#### Example output traceroute/ping

##### traceroute/ping [server] ---> [home]: works

```
$ traceroute 192.168.0.153

traceroute to 192.168.0.153 (192.168.0.153), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  1.939 ms  0.876 ms  0.782 ms
 2  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.529 ms  1.473 ms  1.343 ms
 3  192.168.0.153 (192.168.0.153)  48.924 ms  4.720 ms  4.706 ms

$ ping 192.168.0.153

PING 192.168.0.153 (192.168.0.153): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.153: icmp_seq=0 ttl=62 time=33.799 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.153: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=52.068 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.153: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=71.773 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.153: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=92.071 ms

^C
```

##### traceroute/ping [home] ---> [server]: is problematic

```
$ traceroute 10.0.0.100

traceroute to 10.0.0.100 (10.0.0.100), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  rt-ax89x-fb80 (192.168.0.1)  2.688 ms  1.131 ms  0.952 ms
 2  192.168.0.67 (192.168.0.67)  2.493 ms  1.880 ms  1.994 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * * [and so on ...]

$ ping 10.0.0.100

PING 10.0.0.100 (10.0.0.100): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
92 bytes from rt-ax89x-fb80 (192.168.0.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.0.67)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 fd53   0 0000  3f  01 b2b0 192.168.0.153  10.0.0.100

Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
92 bytes from rt-ax89x-fb80 (192.168.0.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.0.67)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 c4a2   0 0000  3f  01 eb61 192.168.0.153  10.0.0.100

^C
```

Now this isn't a "problem" in the sense that I'm looking for a complete solution - my colleague already showed me a way better setup that I'm going to implement (router on a stick).

However, I want to take this as a learning exercise and trying to learn what actually went wrong and how I could fix the issue.

I've been trying to look into the traffic with Wireshark from both sides (server and home) but this didn't really help me.

My concrete questions:

**• Why is my network behaving this way?**

**• How can I make it work using the topology in the picture? / What would I need to change to make it work using my existing gear.**

---

For completeness:

TP-Link Gateway Router is ER605.

ASUS Router is RT-AX89X.

If someone is wondering why I choose this setup in the first place it's because I didn't want to touch anything that already existed in our home-network. I basically wanted to "add" my server-network with another router (ER605). I don't intend to have my home and server-network use the same subnet.

---

#### Additional information (as requested)

##### Routing Table "Server" (10.0.0.100):

```
$ netstat -rn

Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            10.0.0.1           UGScg         bridge1
10/24              link#32            UCS           bridge1      !
10.0.0.1/32        link#32            UCS           bridge1      !
10.0.0.1           30.de.4b.5d.67.66  UHLWIir       bridge1   1185
10.0.0.100/32      link#32            UCS           bridge1      !
10.0.0.100         48.65.ee.12.e8.c5  UHLWI             lo0
10.0.0.255         ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff  UHLWbI        bridge1      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0
169.254            link#32            UCS           bridge1      !
224.0.0/4          link#32            UmCS          bridge1      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#32            UCS           bridge1      !
```

##### Routing Table "ASUS Router" (192.168.0.1):

```
(exported  via web interface)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.99.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth3
1.1.1.1         192.168.99.1    255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth3
8.8.8.8         192.168.99.1    255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth3
10.0.0.0        192.168.0.67    255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 br0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
192.168.99.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth3
192.168.99.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth3
```

##### Routing Table "TP-Link Gateway" (192.168.0.67/10.0.0.1):

```
Unable to extract (yet)
```

##### Routing Table "Client" (192.168.0.153):

```
$ netstat -rn

Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScg             en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS               en0      !
192.168.0          link#5             UCS               en0      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#5             UCS               en0      !
192.168.0.1        f0:2f:74:c4:fb:85  UHLWIir           en0   1167
192.168.0.31       ba:74:92:62:d5:89  UHLWIi            en0   1179
192.168.0.46       ce:d5:3e:13:3e:47  UHLWI             en0   1187
192.168.0.153/32   link#5             UCS               en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#5             UmCS              en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCS               en0      !
```

Comment: what is the problem you want solved?  See [how do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BlindSpots Excuse me but this should be **pretty** obvious. Have you read the _entire_ question? `traceroute` and `ping` don't work so the obvious problem is to get that working (because in a normal network this works).

Comment: In any case, I've added a "concrete questions" section to be extra clear.

Comment: Doesn't look like a routing issue to me - 10.0.0.100 is accessible. Looks like it's simply configured to drop ICMP packets.

Comment: As for the questions - you should provide routing tables from all of the devices in the data path. Otherwise this is just a guessing game :-) Wireshark traces taken from the client (I assume .0.153) and server side would help. If possible, I'd configure the .0.100 port to be mirrored on the port where .0.X is connected, and run the trace on .0.X.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thank you. You've been **very** helpful so far. I think you're right about the ICMP packets and I recall reading that `ping` alone shouldn't be used to check for connectivity. I will update my question with the routing tables and may try that capture (tomorrow, I think) with Wireshark you suggested.

Comment: Actually ICMP echo (i.e. ping) exists precisely for that, checking if the target device is up 'n running. Traceroute also uses ICMP echo packets. If something else needs to be checked like whether ports are open you need to use other tools. Or if ICMP is blocked :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 I was able to get the routing tables from 3 of the 4 devices in the chain. I don't know how I can extract the routing table from the TP-Link router as the web-interface does not allow me to export it...

Comment: @Peregrino69 I can confirm that enabling ICMP packets resolved the issue with `traceroute` on the home-network client! `ping` also works but occasionally still prints `new addr: 192.168.0.67`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144617/discussion-between-peregrino69-and-marco).

Comment: @Peregrino69 I'm happy to hear that you found a new device through my question! :-) I hope this message gets through because apparently I'm suspended from chatting (for whatever reason). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Got it yes :-) You can talk to moderators abt chat suspension in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator?tab=general - I'd assume it doesn't apply to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the topology and the info there seems to be nothing wrong with routing per se, as 10.0.0.100 is reachable. The likely cause for `ping` / `traceroute` failure is that 10.0.0.100 is configured to drop ICMP packets (both tools rely on ICMP echo).

The ASUS router is designated as the gateway for 192.168.0.0/24 network. However in this topology it's acting as a router only between 192.168.0.0/24 network and the internet. Traffic between it and 10.0.0.0/24 network is switched, and routed in the TP-Link.

While there's nothing exactly wrong with this kind of setup, it's unnecessarily complex. The ASUS router is a regular off-the-shelf SoHo Wi-Fi router, TP-Link is a far more capable device. The way I'd realize this is:

1. Configure the TP-Link to be default gateway for both internal networks
2. Remove the now-redundant ASUS WAN link

The TP-link will then perform all routing between the LAN segments, and between the LAN and the WAN. It can also provide DHCP service for 10.0.0.0/24 network.

The ASUS will act as a LAN switch and a Wi-Fi AP. It can also provide DHCP service for 192.168.0.0/24 network.

As the TP-Link is VLAN-capable, I'd ideally configure it as a DHCP server for both subnets. Unfortunately the [emulator](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/emulator/) doesn't show DHCP at all, and the [manual](https://static.tp-link.com/upload/manual/2022/202208/20220830/1910013241_ER605(UN)2.0_UG.pdf) says nothing about per-VLAN DHCP, so I can only assume it has just one available pool.